# Python dataframe: pivot on same column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns "ID" and "division" as shown below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['111', 'AAA'],['222','AAA'],['333','BBB'],['444','CCC'],['444','AAA'],['222','BBB'],['111','BBB']]),columns=['ID','division'])

    ID  division
0   111 AAA
1   222 AAA
2   333 BBB
3   444 CCC
4   444 AAA
5   222 BBB
6   111 BBB
```

The expected output is as shown below where I need to pivot on the same column but the count is dependent on "division". This should be presented in a heatmap.

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['0','2','1','1'],['2','0','1','1'],['1','1','0','0'],['1','1','0','0']]),columns=['111','222','333','444'],index=['111','222','333','444'])

    111 222 333 444
111 0   2   1   1
222 2   0   1   1
333 1   1   0   0
444 1   1   0   0
```

So, technically I am doing an overlap between ID's with respect to division.

Example: 
The highlighted box in red where the overlap between 111 and 222 ID's is 2(AAA and BBB). where as the overlap between 111 and 444 is 1 (AAA highlighted in the black box).

[image]

I could do this in excel in 2 steps.Not sure if below one helps.
Step1:=`SUM(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$8,$B2,$A$2:$A$8,$G2),COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$8,$B2,$A$2:$A$8,H$1))-1`
Step2:=`IF($G12=H$1,0,SUMIFS(H$2:H$8,$G$2:$G$8,$G12))`

But is there any way that we can do it in Python using dataframes.
Appreciate your help

**Case-2**

```
if df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['111', 'AAA','4'],['222','AAA','5'],['333','BBB','6'],
                            ['444','CCC','3'],['444','AAA','2'], ['222','BBB','2'],
                            ['111','BBB','7']]),columns=['ID','division','count'])

   ID   division count
0   111  AAA      4
1   222  AAA      5
2   333  BBB      6
3   444  CCC      3
4   444  AAA      2
5   222  BBB      2
6   111  BBB      7
```

Expected output would be

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['0','18','13','6'],['18','0','8','7'],['13','8','0','0'],['6','7','0','0']]),columns=['111','222','333','444'],index=['111','222','333','444'])

   111 222  333 444
111 0   18  13  6
222 18  0   8   7
333 13  8   0   0
444 6   7   0   0
```

Calculation: Here there is an overlap between 111 and 222 with respect to divisions AAA and BBB hence the sum would be 4+5+2+7=18

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**. This means no pictures, please. You can use `df.head().to_dict()` to paste dataframe data into your question. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, updated with code but for easy explanation I kept a picture. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another way to do this is to use a self join with `merge` and `pd.crosstab`:

```
df_out = df.merge(df, on='division')

results = pd.crosstab(df_out.ID_x, df_out.ID_y) 
np.fill_diagonal(results.values, 0)
```

Output:

```
ID_y  111  222  333  444
ID_x                    
111   0.0  2.0  1.0  1.0
222   2.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
333   1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
444   1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
```

### Case 2

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['111', 'AAA','4'],['222','AAA','5'],['333','BBB','6'],
                            ['444','CCC','3'],['444','AAA','2'], ['222','BBB','2'],
                            ['111','BBB','7']]),columns=['ID','division','count'])

df['count'] = df['count'].astype(int)
df_out = df.merge(df, on='division')

df_out = df_out.assign(count = df_out.count_x + df_out.count_y)

results = pd.crosstab(df_out.ID_x, df_out.ID_y, df_out['count'], aggfunc='sum').fillna(0) 
np.fill_diagonal(results.values, 0)
```

Output:

```
ID_y   111   222   333  444
ID_x                       
111    0.0  18.0  13.0  6.0
222   18.0   0.0   8.0  7.0
333   13.0   8.0   0.0  0.0
444    6.0   7.0   0.0  0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution helps. Just wondering was there any reason of using 'crosstab' instead of 'pivot_table'. Code

`table = pivot_table(df_out, values='count', index=['ID_x'],
                 columns=['ID_y'], aggfunc=np.sum).fillna(0)`

Comment: @harish I didn't have a reason.  I just choose pd.crosstab probably because I had just used crosstab in another solution elsewhere.  pivot_table works also.

Comment: Thanks this helps