# Best way to create a 3-way Venn Diagram comparing Dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 different dataframes with a group of codes and categories. Between these 3 I am effectively trying to determine where there is overlap on a number/category level. The best way I can describe my desired end result is to have a 3 circle venn diagram labeling codes/categories where all 3 match, just 2 overlap, and just within 1 of them.

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({"num": [1,2,3,4], "cat": ["cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4"]})
d2 = pd.DataFrame({"num": [3,4,5,6], "cat": ["cat1", "cat1", "cat3", "cat4"]})
d3 = pd.DataFrame({"num": [1,2,5,6], "cat": ["cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4"]})
```

desired output:

```
d1/2/3: count unique to d1/2/3 only
d1 and d2 no d3: count in d1 and d2 but not in d3
d1 and d3 no d2: count in d1 and d3 but not in d2
```

....

The best way I have come up with doing this is to create a concatenated column of num/cat and then inner joining each of the dataframes separately and counting the results but I am hoping there is a better, easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking in the future. I was able to take some of the code from this answer and modify it slightly...

[Python dataframe: pivot on same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49373537/python-dataframe-pivot-on-same-column)